# Initialise empty JQuery Datatables and add items to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to initialise an empty datatable and add items to it. My datatable is populated from an array. However, when I add items to the array and refresh the datatable, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'data' of null
    at _fnBuildAjax (jquery.dataTables.js:3962)
    at __reload (jquery.dataTables.js:7582)
    at _Api.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.js:7640)
    at _Api.iterator (jquery.dataTables.js:7029)
    at _Api.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.js:7639)
    at Object.reload (jquery.dataTables.js:7197)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (Create:77)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.js:5183)
    at HTMLDocument.elemData.handle (jquery-3.3.1.js:4991)
    at Object.trigger (jquery-3.3.1.js:8249)
```

This is my datatables code:

```
    var data = ["Test"]
    var data2 = ["Test2"]
    var dataSet = [];
    dataSet.push(data);
    dataSet.push(data2);
    var rowItem = "";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $("#table").DataTable({
            "data": dataSet,
            "filter":false,
            "language": {
                "search": "",
                "searchPlaceholder": " Search"
            },
            "select": {
                "style": 'multi'
            },
            "ordering": true,
            "lengthChange": false,
            "columns": [
               { "title": "Name"},
            ],
            "responsive": true,
            "processing":true,
        }).columns.adjust()
        .responsive.recalc();
        new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader(table);
```

This is how I add items to the array and reload the table:

```
    $(document).on($.modal.AFTER_CLOSE, function (event, modal) {
        console.log(dataSet);
        dataSet.push([rowItem]);
        table.ajax.reload();
        $("#modal").empty();
    });
```

Why does it say my dataSet is null? When I show it on the console, its contains the first 2 preloaded items and the next few I have added to it.

Comment: where is ajax for datatanle?

Comment: The ajax for adding an entry to a datatable?

Comment: ajax for datatable, you can  define ajax in datatable, so initially you can load nothing, and later can call ajax.reload() function anywhere and anytime, will reload table with new data

Comment: ajax.reload() is located in my last code block.

Comment: but you have to init ajax in datatable, , ajax.reload is a way to recall ajax, not initializing it

Comment: Oh. No this is a local datatable using the array as a datasource. It does not use ajax.

Comment: ok then it wont work with ajax,   try this  table.draw();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ajax is for server side requests,
and for javascript array or local array based datatanles you need to use

> table.draw()

and when you have ajax , you need to init

> serverside:true and then use ajax.reload();

```
$(document).on($.modal.AFTER_CLOSE, function (event, modal) {
    console.log(dataSet);
      table.clear();
      table.rows.add(dataSet);
      table.draw();
      $("#modal").empty();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: If you see my items, for some reason the table only works if I keep them within square brackets like this [var]. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: because its the  format for data array that datatable reads, array of arrays ,

Comment: I see. Thank you

Comment: each array is one row and then all together in one array, [here](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array)